# Habilitar/Deshabilitar botones mediante JS y/o PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una consulta de la cual saco un **array** con **`PHP`** y **`MYSQL`**, cada fila debe tener un botón, estas filas las muestro en una tabla **HTML**, lo que deseo hacer es habilitar botón por botón, o sea, que el usuario no acceda a todos los botones, quiero que vaya en orden, uno por uno.

Gracias de antemano.

```
if (isset($_GET["ver_temas"])) 
{
    $curso_id = $_GET['ver_temas'];
    //echo $curso_id;
    global $conexion, $curso, $temas, $archivo, $video;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `temas`
            WHERE curso_id='$curso_id'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
}

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { $temaid = $row["id"];?>


            <table class="table">

                <td width="3%" style="background-color: white; border-color: #AAAAAA" ><strong><h5><?php echo($n); ?></h5></strong></td>
                <td width="40%" style="background-color: white; border-color: #AAAAAA"><strong><h4><?php echo $row["tema"]; ?> </h4></strong></td>
                <td class="" width="20%" style="background-color: white; border-color: #AAAAAA"><center>
```

Y este es el botón que se genera por cada fila.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success tema-btn example_A" href="tema.php?tema_view=<?php echo $row['id']?>"> Ver tema... </a></center>
                </td>


            </table>


    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hola, agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Y que determina o cual es la condición para que el **botón** este habilitado  o no este habilitado   ? .... y estas diciendo en tu pregunta -- `lo que deseo hacer es habilitar botón por botón o sea, que el usuario no acceda a todos los botones` ??? no entiendo supongo que lo que quieres hacer es inhabilitar los botones

Comment: El propósito es que el usuario no se "salte" los temas, que vaya en orden

Comment: La tabla la creas con un ciclo, no? supongo, y agregalo

Comment: Efectivamente .

Comment: @EnriqueE.Molina agregalo que tengo una idea

Comment: La idea es que vaya habilitando uno después del otro ?, entonces como validas si si cumplió con el tema ? solo si presiona el botón ? Mejor dicho si presiona el botón 1 habilite el botón 2 y si presiona el botón 2 habilite el botón tres ? ese es el comportamiento que quieres que tenga ?

Comment: En el código que publiqué uso la sentencia **while** para generar la tabla ^^. Guardo en una tabla el avance, despues de que termina un video,

Comment: Ah, ya @EnriqueE.Molina es que están separados, ya te muestro lo que tengo

Comment: Estás aplicando bootstrap?

Comment: Efectivamente..

Comment: @EnriqueE.Molina revisalo y me comentas

Comment: @EnriqueE.Molina Revisa el ejemplo que deje, y me avisas si es lo que necesitas

Comment: @EnriqueE.Molina Te sirvió alguna de las respuestas ? , no olvides marcarla como aceptada para que sea de utilidad para otros usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las ideas que tengo es colocándole `id` a cada uno de los botones, entonces, lo que se haría es que apenas se oprima el botón, eso llame un método que le tome el `id` y lo de por hecho, por ende habilita el siguiente, algo más o menos así.

`HTML`

```
<a type="button" id="<?php echo $n ?> onclick="guardarId(this)" class="btn btn-success tema-btn example_A disabled" href="tema.php?tema_view=<?php echo $row['id']?>"> Ver tema... </a></center>
```

`JS`

```
function guardarId(btn){
   localStorage.setItem("id", btn.id);
}

function habilitarBtn(){
   if(localStorage.getItem("id") != null){
      var id = localStorage.getItem("id");
      var btn = document.getElementById(parseInt(id) + 1);
      var otrobtn = document.getElementById(id+1);
      otrobtn.classList.remove("disabled");
      button.classList.add("disabled");
   }else{
      var btn = document.getElementById("1");
      btn.classList.remove("disabled");
   }
}

habilitarBtn();
```

Algo más o menos de esta forma, alguna cosa, duda o sugerencia, me comentas. Espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo revisaré. Saludos!

Comment: @EnriqueE.Molina me acabo de dar cuenta de una cosa e hice unos cambios, ya que tú al darle al botón lo rediriges a otra pagina, entonces lo que estaba haciendo anteriormente no serviría, se perdería, en esta ocasión se guarda la variable y no se pierde aunque navegues

Comment: Vale, gracias por ese dato!

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional con **`JS`** , del comportamiento que quieres que tenga tu tabla, Lo que hice fue asignar un **id** al botón cuando la lleno y en el botón que creo agrega un método que valida cual es el siguiente id que llega y lo habilito, lo hago con una **`funcion`** que remueve el `disabled` del botón  y tengo una validación para que el primer **`boton`** se cree sin el **`disabled`**.

Espero te sirva , Prueba el snippet

```js
 
 $('document').ready(() => {
       var ArrayTable = {1: 'a' , 2: 'b', 3: 'c'};
      
       $.each(ArrayTable, function (index, value) {
       console.log(index + ' ' + value)
         if(index == 1){
          $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+ index +"</td> "+ 
         "<td><input type='submit' value='ir al curso' id='Column"+index+"' onclick='habilitarBtn("+index+")'></td></tr>");
         } else {
            $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+ index +"</td> "+ 
         "<td><input type='submit' value='ir al curso' id='Column"+index+"' disabled onclick='habilitarBtn("+index+")'></td></tr>");
         }
      });
 });
 
 
 function habilitarBtn(index) {
  const Siguiente = index + 1;

  $('#Column'+Siguiente+'').removeAttr("disabled");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Columna<th>
      <th>ir al curso<th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id"myTable">
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Comment: Gracias! Lo revisaré :D